# Set value in 'ROWorder' as highest value in 'ROWorder' + 1

Tags: mysql

Here's my query, which doesn't break - but it doesn't work, either. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
$sql_query="UPDATE requests 
            SET Playlisted=1, 
                ROWorder=(SELECT MAX(ROWorder) + 1) 
            WHERE IDrequests=".$_GET['Playlisted_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the aggregation in a subquery:

```
UPDATE requests r CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(ROWorder) as maxro FROM requests) rr
    SET Playlisted = 1,
        ROWorder= maxrr  + 1
    WHERE IDrequests = ".$_GET['Playlisted_id'];
```

That should fix the syntax problem.  It is not immediately obvious what the code is supposed to be doing.  Often, this type of operation is handled on `insert` using an `auto_increment` column, but you might have some other use case.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to update the 'requests' table with this query, but force the update to the bottom of the results returned to the user (by way of the 'ROWorder' value. The table already has a primary key auto_increment column which is being used for a relationship with another table. Unfortunately, your syntax doesn't break the query, but it doesn't do the update either.